# Windows SBS 2008: Join domain from external network via a VPN Connection

Tags: join, dns, vpn, windows-sbs

I have a VPN Connection connecting two LANs. One of them has a Windows SBS 2008 Server which is the Domain Controller for our Domain. Its IP address is 192.168.4.3 with the router/gateway 192.168.4.1.

The other LAN has a router/gateway 192.168.8.1, and I would like to join the Domain on the above mentioned network from this network.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Thanks. Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You may know this by now but SBS 2008 will only support class "C" networks. I believe the trusted network of the form 192.168.8.x on the remote side of the VPN cannot be supported.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the IP-Adress of the Server in your Clients DNS-Settings (VPN-Interface). If you try to join with SBS DNS it should work.